# tvservice command from php fails (Failed to initialize VCHI)

Tags: hdmi, permissions

I want to be able to turn HDMI on and off from a web page. I have written this script:

```
$power = $_GET['power'];
if ($power === 'on') {
  echo "<h1>Switching TV on</h1>";

  $output = shell_exec('tvservice -p');
  echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
}
else  {
  echo "<h1>Switching TV off</h1>";

  $output = shell_exec('tvservice -o');
 echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
}
```

The script doesn't have any effect, and doesn't produce any output. When I execute a **tvservice** command as user PI, it works:

> pi@loungepi /home/mike $ tvservice -p
>   Powering on HDMI with preferred settings

When I run the same command as www-data, it fails:

> $ tvservice -p
>   [E] Failed to initialize VCHI (ret=-1)

What do I have to do so that www-data can execute **tvservice** commands?

Comment: add user `www-data` to the `video` group ... i.e. `sudo adduser www-data video`